# Alguém consegue me explicar a estrutura do Git com o GitHub?

Tags: git, eclipse, github

Eu estou tentando configurar o Git com o GitHub, mas não estou conseguindo alguém consegue me ajudar com isso? Sistema operacional Windows 10.

Exemplo: Eu uso o Eclipse e os meus projetos são criados no diretório padrão C:\Users\Diego\workspace\ em minha máquina local, o meu repositório criado no site GitHub é o de nome Projetos, como eu devo proceder para conseguir configurar o Git, subir os meus projetos no Github, e também gostaria de saber se tem como subir os já criados também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Exemplo: Eu uso o Eclipse e os meus projetos são criados no diretório
>   padrão C:\Users\Diego\workspace\ em minha máquina local, o meu
>   repositório criado no site GitHub é o de nome Projetos, como eu devo
>   proceder para conseguir configurar o Git..

clone o repositorio com o seguinte comando:

```
$ cd C:\Users\Diego\workspace\Pasta-do-Projeto
$ git clone url-do-repositorio
```

Nesse monento você já tem o seu repositorio local apontando para o projeto no github

> ...e também gostaria de saber saber se tem como subir os já criados
>   também.

crie o repositorio no github correspondente ao seu projeto local, depois de criado, copie a url do projeto.
Acesse a pasta do projeto pelo terminal e use os seguintes comandos

```
$ cd C:\Users\Diego\workspace\Pasta-do-Projeto
$ git init
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/usuario/nomedoprojeto.git
$ git add -A 
$ git commit -m "meu primeiro upload"
$ git push origin master
```

link útil:

- [Configurando o git](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Primeiros-passos-Configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Inicial-do-Git)

Comment: Olá Leonardo. Vou executar esses passos agora e já lhe informe novamente. Obrigado!

Comment: Olá Leonardo. Talvez eu não expressei da forma correta. Eu tenho o diretório criado C:\Users\Diego\workspace\Projetos, eu preciso clonar o meu repositório https://github.com/diegocezarino/Aplicativos através da pasta Projetos ou da workspace? Essa parte eu não to conseguindo entender. Me explique melhor a parte de adicionar um projeto ja criado para o Github. Obrigado!